# Fresh Install of Mint 18 w/ Cinnamon -- randomly logging out, can't log back in

Tags: linux-mint, chrome, crash, thinkpad, logout

A few days ago I made the plunge from Windows and put Linux Mint on my laptop (Thinkpad 440), the newest release. Things are mostly fine, except twice today I've been browsing the internet on Chromium browser, when suddenly and with no warning at all, the system will switch to the login screen background with the clock, but there's nothing I can use to log back in. It's completely unresponsive, no mouse cursor, nothing appears when I type, nothing happens when I shut the laptop lid and open it again. The only thing I can do is hold the power button until it shuts down and I can restart (thankfully Chromium saves my tabs).

Obviously this is not ideal. I can't do any important work if everything might get nuked without warning. What's going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There do seem to be a few oddities with LM 18 at the moment although my install is running beautifully.  This sounds as though the lock screen is being activated and then for some reason you can't get back in - maybe its not recognizing your keyboard activity.

I'd report it so that someone can look at a bug fix however I have two suggestions.

1. Linux Mint 17.3 is a totally stable option if you were in the mood for a reinstall.  New releases, even after beta testing seem to discover these odd software/hardware interactions which take a while to resolve.
2. I turn off the lock screen functionality anyway so why not try that:

   - open System Settings
   - open Screensaver
   - open the Settings tab
   - turn off the "Lock the ..." options or set them to Never

Please tag this as answer if it is a useful workaround, however, do report it as a bug.  The [bug tracker is here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint).

Comment: What I ended up doing was upgrading my BIOS and kernel (recommended on another site). This seemed to fix the problem. Thanks for the reply though!